# AngularJS multiple selection model data binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3.

I have a model y with a 1 to many relationship with model x.

Initially, I had a form for model y with a multiple select for xs, something like this:

Controller:

```
function test($scope) {
  $scope.xs = [
    {id:1, value:'value 1'},
    {id:2, value:'value 2'},
    {id:3, value:'value 3'}
  ];
  $scope.y = {xs:[2]};
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="test">
  <select multiple ng-model="y.xs" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in xs">
  </select>    
</div>
```

The result is an array of the selected items.

http://plnkr.co/edit/s3tvvHeyE17TVH5KNkPZ

All fine and good, but I needed to change it to a checkbox list and found I couldn't use an array anymore.

I tried using the repeater's index, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in xs">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="y.xs[$index]" ng-true-value="{{x.id}}"/>
  {{x.value}}
</div>
```

but to pre-select the 2nd item for example, I needed to use this:

```
$scope.y = {xs: [null, '2']};
```

which was useless.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9UfbKF2gFLnhTOKu3Yep

After a bit of searching, it seems the recommended method is to use an object hash, like so

```
<div ng-repeat="x in xs">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="y.xs[x.id]"/>
  {{x.value}}
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xek8alEJbwq3g0NAPMcF

but if items are de-selected, you end up with something that looks like this:

```
y={
  "xs": {
    "1": false,
    "2": false,
    "3": false
  }
}
```

so I ended up adding a watch expression to filter out the false values, like this:

```
$scope.$watch('y.xs', function(n) {
  for (var k in n) 
    if (n.hasOwnProperty(k) && !n[k]) 
      delete n[k];
}, true);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/S1C1g5fYKzUZb7b0pRtp

It works but it feels unsatisfactory.

As this is such a common use case, I'm interested to know how others are solving it.

**Update**

Following the suggestion to use a custom directive, I came up with this solution which maintains the selection as a list.

Directive:

```
angular.module('checkbox', [])
.directive('checkboxList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      selection: '=',
      items: '=',
      value: '@',
      label: '@'
    },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in list">' +
      '<label>' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="{{item.value}}" ng-checked="item.checked" ng-click="toggle($index)"/>' +
      '{{item.label}}' +
      '</label>' +
      '</div>',
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.toggle = function (index) {
        var item = $scope.list[index],
          i = $scope.selection.indexOf(item.value);
        item.checked = !item.checked;
        if (!item.checked && i > -1) {
          $scope.selection.splice(i, 1);
        } else if (item.checked && i < 0) {
          $scope.selection.push(item.value);
        }
      };
      $scope.$watch('items', function (value) {
        $scope.list = [];
        if (angular.isArray(value)) {
          angular.forEach(value, function (item) {
            $scope.list.push({
              value: item[$scope.value],
              label: item[$scope.label],
              checked: $scope.selection.indexOf(item[$scope.value]) > -1
            });
          });
        }
      }, true);
    }]
  };
});
```

View:

```
<div checkbox-list
     selection="a.bs"
     items="bs"
     value="id"
     label="name">
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/m7yH9bMPuRCg5OP2u0VX

Comment: Your AngularJS example, showing how to bind to a "multiple select" control  to a JSON array, has just saved me a lot of time - thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a multi select directive myself in the past, feel free to grab it at http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select.

As for the data binding approach, my data structure is actually quite similar with yours, but in my approach I added one more property which represent the checkbox state.

Example, with your input above, I added "checked":

```
$scope.xs = [
    { id:1, value:'value 1', checked: false },
    { id:2, value:'value 2', checked: false },
    { id:3, value:'value 3', checked: false }
];
```

And I pass it to the directive like this:

```
<div 
    multi-select 
    input-model="xs" 
    button-label="value" 
    item-label="id value" 
    tick-property="checked" >
</div>
```

When you tick / untick a checkbox, the directive will modify the input model $scope.xs.checked accordingly. To achieve this, i attach a click handler to each checkbox. This handler will call a function in which I pass the checkbox object as the function parameter. This function will then synchronize the checkbox state and the model.

To get the selected / ticked checkboxes, you will only need to loop `$scope.xs` over where `.checked === true`

Example:

```
angular.forEach( $scope.xs, function( value, key ) {
    if ( value.checked === true ) {
         // Do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Pardon my bad English, and hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I went the directive approach. It leaves me with a list of ids for the objects that are checked. This is a fiddle for it [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/t7kr8/).
This is what my html looks like.

```
<div ng-app="checkbox" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group />
        <label>{{item.value}}</label>
    </div>{{array}}
    <br>{{update()}}
</div>
```

And my directive

```
.directive("checkboxGroup", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            // Determine initial checked boxes
            if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
                elem[0].checked = true;
            }

            // Update array on click
            elem.bind('click', function () {
                var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id);
                // Add if checked
                if (elem[0].checked) {
                    if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.id);
                }
                // Remove if unchecked
                else {
                    if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                }
                // Sort and update DOM display
                scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a - b
                }));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With my requirement to maintain the selection as an ordered list, a custom directive is the way to go. I implemented a custom directive a bit differently to yours. I'll update my question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a checkbox solution that would also display values that were not in the list of possible choices (what if that list had changed since the user filled out the form?).

Also, I didn't think a watch function was necessary.

Finally, I needed to pass in the form in so I could set it to dirty if the user had toggled any of the checkboxes.

Caveat: In my case I only needed an array of strings as my model, which isn't exactly what the poster was using for his model.

HTML:

```
<multiple-checkbox
    form="form"
    selections="model"
    options="options">
</multiple-checkbox>
```

Directive:

```
.directive("multipleCheckbox", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            form: '=',
            selections: '=',
            options: '=',
        },
        template:
            '<div>' +
                '<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in options">' +
                    '<label>' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" value="{{$index}}" ng-checked="selections.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggle(item)"/>' +
                        '{{item}}' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in selections" ng-if="options.indexOf(item) === -1">' +
                    '<label>' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" value="{{options.length + $index}}" ng-checked="selections.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggle(item)"/>' +
                        '<strong>Other: </strong>{{item}}' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            // Executed when the checkboxes are toggled
            $scope.toggle = function (item) {

                // set the form to dirty if we checked the boxes
                if ($scope.form) $scope.form.$dirty = true;

                // get the index of the selection
                var index = -1;
                if (angular.isArray($scope.selections)) {
                    index = $scope.selections.indexOf(item);
                }
                // if it's not already an array, initialize it
                else $scope.selections = [];

                if (index > -1) {
                    // remove the item
                    $scope.selections.splice(index, 1);
                    // if the array is empty, set it to null
                    if ($scope.selections.length === 0) {
                        $scope.selections = null;
                    }
                }
                else if (index < 0) {
                    // add the item
                    $scope.selections.push(item);
                }

            };
        }],
    };
});
```